# Getting NullPointerException (Name is null) when querying a Glue table using Spark SQL on EMR

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr, apache-zeppelin, aws-glue

I've set up an AWS EMR with Spark and Zeppelin and with AWS Glue catalog as the metastore for Hive. I used this instruction: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-glue.html

It seems that the EMR cluster and Zeppeling are working.

When I run the following paragraph:

```
%sql
show databases
```

It works and outputs my databases set up in Glue.

However, when I try to query any of the tables, this way:

```
%sql
select * from `fus-bear-parquet-db-prod`.fus_bear_parquet_prod limit 10
```

I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Name is null
at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:236)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.getTableType(Table.java:401)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$getTableOption$1$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:394)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$getTableOption$1$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:373)
at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$getTableOption$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:373)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$getTableOption$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:371)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$withHiveState$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:290)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.liftedTree1$1(HiveClientImpl.scala:231)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.retryLocked(HiveClientImpl.scala:230)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.withHiveState(HiveClientImpl.scala:273)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.getTableOption(HiveClientImpl.scala:371)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClient$class.getTable(HiveClient.scala:75)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.getTable(HiveClientImpl.scala:79)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$getRawTable$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:118)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$getRawTable$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:118)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:97)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.getRawTable(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:117)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$getTable$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:675)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$getTable$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:675)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:97)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.getTable(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:674)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.lookupRelation(SessionCatalog.scala:667)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$lookupTableFromCatalog(Analyzer.scala:646)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.resolveRelation(Analyzer.scala:601)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$8.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:631)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$8.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:624)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolveOperators$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:62)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolveOperators$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:62)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperators(LogicalPlan.scala:61)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:59)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:59)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperators(LogicalPlan.scala:59)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:59)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:59)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperators(LogicalPlan.scala:59)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:59)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:59)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperators(LogicalPlan.scala:59)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.apply(Analyzer.scala:624)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.apply(Analyzer.scala:570)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:85)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:82)
at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:124)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:84)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:82)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:74)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:74)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:69)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:67)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:50)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:67)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:632)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:691)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkSqlInterpreter.interpret(SparkSqlInterpreter.java:116)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:97)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:498)
at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:175)
at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:139)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you ever find a solution?

Thanks, Drew

Comment: I've made an experiment and changed the CloudFormation script and added "TableType:EXTERNAL_TABLE". This fixed the issue with "java.lang.NullPointerException: Name is null".

Athena doesn't require this attribute and uses EXTERNAL TABLE as a default when it's absent. I believe EMR could do the same.

Comment: Thanks so much Andrey. Can you tell me exactly where you put TableType:EXTERNAL_TABLE ? I'm getting this exact error in PySpark.

Comment: I was missing it in my CloudFormation template where I declared the table. Check how you created your table. Apparently it doesn't have table type specified.

Comment: Was able to resolve this based on your feedback! Thanks so much for your time @Andrey

Answer (score 1):

*I will rephrase @Andrey Cheptsov's comment as an answer as this is solving the problem and this way will be more prominent for others facing the same issue. Thanks Andrey!*

The problem is caused by the [`TableType`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/webapi/API_Table.html) (*EXTERNAL_TABLE, VIRTUAL_VIEW, etc.*) property not being set for the table. It's set automatically when creating tables from Athena, but can get forgotten when using Cloudformation or Terraform.

To solve the problem make sure you add the `TableType` property to you table and re-try the query.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the CDK I could fix that by using the `table_type`

```
aws_glue.CfnTable.TableInputProperty(description="My Description",name="my_table_name",table_type="EXTERNAL_TABLE",...,)
```

Using only CloudFormation:

```
"GlueTable": {
      "Type": "AWS::Glue::Table",
      "Properties": {
        "CatalogId": {
          "Ref": "AWS::AccountId"
        },
        "DatabaseName": "my_data_base_name",
        "TableInput": {
          "Description": "My Description",
          "Name": "my_table_name",
          ...
          "TableType": "EXTERNAL_TABLE"
        }
      }
    }
```